# saveToCameraRoll is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to send images which are taken using React Native Camera library to Camera Roll.

When the user presses a button the following function gets triggered:

```
  takePicture = async function() {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true }
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri)
    }
  }
```

I already know that the app sends pictures to the cache folder because after this code is executed a link to the picture is displayed:

```
  takePicture = async function() {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true }
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
      console.log(data.uri)
    }
  }
```

The debugger shows the following error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0)
React Native Camera: TypeError: _reactNative.default.saveToCameraRoll is not a function
```

The code of the Cam component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native'
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera'
import CameraRoll from 'react-native'
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  button: {
    height: 200,

    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  actionButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 22,
    color: 'white',
  },

});


export default class Cam extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.takePicture = this.takePicture.bind(this)
  }

  takePicture = async function() {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true }
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {this.camera = ref}}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
            position: 'relative'
          }}
        >
        </RNCamera>

        <ActionButton size={80} useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)">
          <ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#9b59b6' title="Settings" onPress={this.props.switchScreen}>
            <Icon name="md-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="Start" onPress={this.takePicture}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>

        </ActionButton>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this just a bit of debug info from React, or is it an actual failure?

Comment: Only a bit of debug info. The application just continues to work although the pictures which are taken aren't sent to the Camera Roll.

Comment: How does your`CameraRoll` import looks like ?

Comment: Updated my initial post with all the code.

Comment: Seems like your import should be `import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native';`

Comment: Thank you, now all I have to do is to set up the permissions. It seems that it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this [example](https://medium.com/react-native-training/mastering-the-camera-roll-in-react-native-13b3b1963a2d) of how to use `CameraRoll`  :

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  CameraRoll,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native'
```

---

You have to replace :

```
import CameraRoll from 'react-native';
```

by

```
import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native';
```

*(I've put it as an answer so it can be accepted and close the question)*

---

---

In your code, you can mutualise the imports like :

```
import React, {
  Component,
} from 'react';

import { 
   RNCamera,
} from 'react-native-camera';

import {
  CameraRoll,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```